# Trigger code-generation in a VS project template

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2013

I created a project template that has a SQL database and a Linq2SQL dbml file. A project created using this template will not compile due to apparent missing code, but if you right-click on the dbml file and invoke `Run Custom Tool` the missing code is generated and thereafter compilation succeeds.

What do I need to do to my project template so that it triggers code-generation? I'm aware of the IWizard extension system for project templates, but I have no idea how to programmatically cause the IDE to perform code generation.

So the question is: *How, in a Wizard implementation for use in a project template, do you trigger IDE code generation?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible method could be adding a pre-Build event to your project which runs a batch file [transformer.bat] and performs your transformation:

Get the list of files which need to be transformed using something like the following in the transformer.bat:

```
dir %wdir%\*.tt /b /s > myFiles.txt
```

and run [TextTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx) Utility against them similar to the following:

```
for /f %%d in (myFiles.txt) do (
set file_name=%%d
set file_name=!file_name:~0,-3!.%extension%
TextTransform.exe -out !file_name! %%d
)
```

The key here is the pre-Build event and creating the batch file which runs the TextTransform Utility.

If you are more leaned towards [MSBuild integration](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/) you need to come up with somehting like the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
.....
```

In your tt files.

[Transforming Templates in a build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx)